# Node.js project with no package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

Is it ok to have a node.js project with no package.json? The ones I see on the internet all come with package.json

What is the effect of having no package.json?

How is package.json created in the first place? Is it created automatically? I am wondering why I do not have package.json

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Fundamentally, `package.json` is a meta file for your application. It lists all the configuration of your application.

> What is the effect of having no package.json?

Nothing as far as you're running all your code locally and have no requirement for deployment whatsoever.

Let's setup a scene for you to understand this better.
Imagine that you wrote a brilliant application using node. Now all the chicks in your surrounding want it to play with. It is so fantastic!
Now you want to give it to them and during the development process you `npm install`ed so many things that your project grows beyond 4TB size.

There is no data storage device available to ship that huge code base.

Then the girl of your dream said I want it and I want it now. So you begin searching for app deployment process for node applications.

That is where you stumble upon a magical thing called `package.json`.

So what you do is you list all your `npm install`ed modules under `dependencies` property. Then you delete `node_modules`folder, add `package.json` and commit the entire damn thing in github. Even the `.zip` file is of `10MB`

Then she gets the code.
Types in `npm install && npm start` (which will install all the dependencies from the package.json` and start your application)

If you have package.json however, that is where you specify all your dependencies.

Using `--save` flag of `npm install`

Example.

`npm install express --save`

> How is package.json created in the first place? Is it created automatically?

You can manually create a text file and save it as `package.json`

OR

A more sophisticated way is to use the command

`npm init`

> I am wondering why I do not have package.json

Me too! :)

You're most probably following a tutorial that doesn't emphasize on initial configuration of the project OR the author of those tutorials presume that the reader has all the fundamentals down to begin with.

Comment: 1 for the story. Hilarious

Comment: I am laughing on laud AF while reading it, it is so simple to understand! Well explained, thank you @AdityaParab :D

Comment: bleh bleh bleh bleh if your are enterprise you just include node_modules with repo because "0 trust" mean 0 trust and re-downloaded nodejs modules break that trust. Last time some junior deves run npm install we got hit with rasom and have to pay 1mln. So when run npm audit i wish to see which package have to update and then compare code changes line by line before update my packages.

Answer (score 10):

It is created automatically if you write `npm init`.

Then, every package you add using `npm install packagename --save` will be added to the dependencies list.

You need `package.json` so that when you want to use your project on another machine you don't have to copy all `node_modules`, but only your `.js` files you have written, assets and `package.json`. You can then run `npm install` command and it will automatically download and install all the required modules (found in the list of dependencies inside `package.json`).

You can also manually create or edit it, but it's easier to add `--save` when installing a module so you don't have to worry about package versions and stuff like that.

Also if you want to create a npm package, an open source project or stuff other people will use, it's either required or the norm to have this `package.json` file describing your project.

Comment: I went straight to `npm install` without running `npm init`. Strange, things still work. I can still call `require <module>`.

Answer (score 1):

package.json is [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) file, if you don't use npm you will not have this file, npm is a great tool if you want to use external libraries in your project but if you don't need it (which is very not likely unless you are doing something very simple), you don't need package.json file too.

To generate package.json file initialize npm in your project using `npm init`

Answer (score 0):

possible reason thus it exist is you maybe you enter a wrong command like `npm i -y`, you must initialize the project first, just enter a command `npm init -y`

Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are running it on your local machine, it's fine. now to answer your last question, package.json is not created automatically.
the npm command `npm init -y` creates the 'package.json' file. It basically makes sharing your code and installing your codebase easier.