# How do I run a JavaScript project with no package.json file present, which therefore gives error when running it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Face-Detection-JavaScript) project. It has no `package.json` file in it. Being an absolute noob with JS, with no JS experience whatsoever, I searched online how to run JS projects. Every link I found seems to assume that the file `package.json` is present. So, you typically do a "npm install" and then "npm start". But since there's no "package.json" file present in this project, running "npm install" doesn't do anything. But when I do "npm start", I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/username/Downloads/Face-Detection-JavaScript-master/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/Downloads/Face-Detection-JavaScript-master/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2020-08-26T04_51_15_254Z-debug.log
```

So, how do I run this project?

I tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468041/npm-install-gives-error-cant-find-a-package-json-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518128/node-js-project-with-no-package-json), but to no avail.

I also tried `node script.js`, but I get the following error:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')
              ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Downloads/Face-Detection-JavaScript-master/script.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

When I open the `index.html` file in browser, I just get a blank page:

[image]

Comment: Looks like this runs in a browser, so you can run a localhost static server, like `python -m http.server` or open the index.html in a browser and see the js files running.

Comment: It’s not clear why you want to “run the project”.  The script files in that repo has already been built and compiled, so all you need is to load the script in a page that you want to use. There is no compilation or building required.

Comment: @R.A.Lucas I have edited the question to include a screenshot of the blank page I get when opening 'index.html' in the web browser.

Comment: @Terry Like I said, I have no idea how JS works. I just wanted to run this project to see how it works. And since I got a blank page when opening index.html in the browser, I assumed I would need to build the project. That's why I was trying to "run the project".

Comment: try adding a `./` after each `src="` in your index.html. also look in the browser developer tools. you will have to look it up for safaria. I know for firefox its ctrl+shift+i. look under the network and see if those scripts are getting loaded.

Comment: @MichaelPollind Tried, doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with Node.js.  All you have to do is open  the HTML file in your browser.

Comment: I have edited the question to include a screenshot of the blank page I get when opening 'index.html' in the web browser.

Comment: @Kristada673 Post a new question, and include your developer tools screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is if you want to run javascript with `node`, for which you need to have node and npm installed, ([installation link here](https://nodejs.org/en/)), and initialize an node project with `npm init --y` to generate a package.json

**But**, in this case though, you just need to run the html file on your browser, and the javascript code will run on the browser, so you don't need to do all that.

Comment: I edited the question to include a screenshot of the blank page I get when opening 'index.html' in the web browser.

Comment: have you first tried the bug fixes provided in the README.MD of the provided github repo?

Comment: Yes, I made that change. Still the same, opening index.html in the browser renders a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Only nodeJS projects need `package.json` . You can run your javascript project by putting your `index.html` or main file directly on browser